# Volkswagen A/C Intermittent

Tags: ac, vw, passat, intermittent-problems

I want to repair my Volkswagen Passat '07 A/C. I've taken it to two shops (dealer and independent) and they both say the entire a/c system needs to be replaced. The strange thing is, that sometimes it actually comes on and when it does it works great. The rest of the time I can't get it to come on at all.

Is there a way to force the A/C to stay on when I tell it? I've heard that there is a limiter that keeps the compressor off when certain sensors are not reading correctly to protect the compressor from damage. In my case though they're recommending replacing the entire system so I don't see any problems forcing it to work until it can't cool anymore. Also does it make sense that I need a new compressor when it works great sometimes?

Comment: What exactly does the entire system include? So far sounds like you need a third opinion.

Comment: compressor, Receiver/Dryer, expansion valve, probably the condenser. They said something about metal shavings in the system from a bad compressor.

Comment: Also to note, the dealership said they could get it working by just replacing the compressor, but that it would fail again over time if I didn't replace the entire system.

Comment: That sounds more reasonable, and if it had an internal compressor failure that's usually the course of action. But if it works sometimes it makes me wonder if it's an internal failure of the compressor. How do they know their is metal in the system? Did they see it, or are they assuming.

Comment: In reality i'm not sure about how the "know", but they acted as if they looked in the system. I never trust the dealership. The independent shop recharged it and that's when it started working intermittently.

Comment: @JMC - have you had any luck with troubleshooting the issue?  If you have resolved it could you post the fix here and award yourself the answer?

Comment: @DucatiKiller - Unfortunately I was unable to find a solution. Due to the repair cost ($2000+), I ended up selling the car instead.

Comment: @JMC - would you mind deleting the question since we will never have a solution so the site stats are good for answered questions?  TIA  :)

Comment: @DucatiKiller actually this question does have a plausible answer. I'm working on it :)

Comment: @Zaid - You get this answer done yet?

Answer (score 3):

If the system is either working fine or not at all then the likely failure is in the control gear for the system, the AC clutch would be my first port of call, you'll need an assistant:

Open the engine bay and look for the AC compressor, it is one of the ancillaries at the side of the engine run by a serpentine belts. The compressor pulley has a clutch built in, so that the pulley always spins, but it only drives the compressor when the AC is switched on (activating the clutch).

[image: AC Clutch]

You can see if the clutch is working by:

1. Locating the AC compressor
2. Starting the engine, with the AC off
3. Observe that the middle of the pulley is stationary, this means that the clutch is not engaged
4. Get your assistant to turn the AC on, you should hear a click and observe that the middle of the pulley is now spinning

If it does not spin then you've either got an electrical fault or the clutch has failed. If the middle of the pulley is not spinning you can try to get a multimeter on the electrical connector and read the voltage when the system is turned on

- If there is 0v you have an electrical fault
- If there is ~12-15v the clutch has failed and the compressor should be replaced

Answer (score 1):

Best first thing to do is to get the error codes read on the car.

I own a 05 Audi and 09 passat. These cars have controllers for everything that read the state of the various car systems using sensors and the AC is one of the more complex units in the car.

If the AC is not working then good chance its detecting a problem and raising a fault code.

Trying to fix an issue without getting the fault codes read is taking a stab in the dark in my opinion.

I use the US made VCDS tool from RossTech. If you post on a forum somewhere you might get someone in your local area willing to do the scan for a small fee ( a sixpack of beers )

Answer (score 0):

The thing that causes a lot of compressors to fail is the thermal expansion valve or orifice tube. Debris gets in there from deteriorating O rings and metal pieces coated with oil. This has the effect of depriving the compressor of refrigerant and oil causing it to fail by overheating. Common occurrence in both Automotive and Residential A/C systems. Being low on refrigerant will do it too...